# react-native how to set fontSize in picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Picker } from 'react-native';

export default class pik extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Picker
        selectedValue={'Hotels'}
        mode={'dropdown'}
        style={{
          height: 50,
          width: 150,
          fontSize: 50,
        }}>
        <Picker.Item style={{ fontSize: 100 }} label="Hotels" value="Hotels" />
        <Picker.Item label="Food" value="Foosd" />
      </Picker>
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

[image]
[image]

**[LIVE DEMO ERROR](https://snack.expo.io/@vijay777pawar/picker-error-1)**

Answer (score -1):

Use [itemStyle](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html#itemstyle) if you want to style to apply to each of the item labels.

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Picker } from 'react-native';

export default class pik extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Picker
        selectedValue={'Hotels'}
        mode={'dropdown'}
        itemStyle={{
          height: 50,
          width: 150,
          fontSize: 50,
        }}>
        <Picker.Item style={{ fontSize: 100 }} label="Hotels" value="Hotels" />
        <Picker.Item label="Food" value="Foosd" />
      </Picker>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for hearing that it is working for me although.

Comment: i tried here https://snack.expo.io/@vijay777pawar/picker-error-1 and also on local machine its not working , i think its version problem ..

Comment: `itemStyle` only works on `iOS` at the moment:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker#itemstyle